# how to pass dropdown selected name value and its id value using BeginForm to controller method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

cshtml -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDevice", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, (SelectList)ViewBag.Name, "---Select Name---")
```

controller method -

```
[httpPost]
public void AddDevice(Registration registration)
        {
```

in html i can get these values -

```
<select name="Name" id="Name"><option value="">---Select Name---</option>
<option value="8d6d30cf-b8cd-4abd-bf38-e975e6a86542">Demo2</option>
</select>
```

I want both these two values into `Registration registration` I got only selected name for now.

How can i get id value also i.e `8d6d30cf-b8cd-4abd-bf38-e975e6a86542` ?

Comment: AFAICT, the Html `select` will send the value and not the text representation. What code are you using to submit the form? can you inspect the body of the POST request?

Comment: I wonder how it post Name instead of value!!?

Comment: With your current code, when the form is submitted, model binder will map the value attribute of the selected option(Guid value) to the `Name` property of `Registration` object. Why do you need to send the text as well  ? You can always query it in your action method using this guid value .rite ?

Comment: yes but instead of query it using guid i have that name there in ui so i thought is there any way to get both values into post method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden field. With javascript you can pass name as value into the hidden field. Then you can get data with hidden field's name.